# Error when Installing pentaho data integration

Tags: installation, pentaho, java-home, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I'm trying to install pentaho data integration and I have a problem with the configuration of spoon.bat. I updated the file with adding `PENTAHO_JAVA= javaw.exe`, also edited the environment variables (Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables by adding ";C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" on the end of the variable PATH. 
but when I start the file, it doesn't work.

I have this error 
DEBUG: Using `JAVA_HOME`
and Windows can't find the path

Comment: in order to run spoon.bat file you only have to set java_home and it should be : C:\Program Files\Java\<jdk folder> ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` should be pointed to a jdk. `JRE_HOME` should point to jre.

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin
JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
PENTAHO_JAVA = 'C:\Pentaho\Java'
```

Change the paths accordingly and try.

Comment: I resolved the problem by deletig \bin from the JAVA_HOME thaaaaaank you :)

Comment: @Fatim select this as the correct answer if this is correct